# ggplot2 geom_dotplot() does not show all dots

Tags: r, ggplot2

I'm trying to show a number of dots per `id` equal to `count`, split by `name` in the following dataframe:

```
df <- data.frame(name = c("name1", "name1", "name1", "name1", "name2", "name2", "name2"),
                 id = c(0, 1, 2, 3, 0, 1, 2),
                 count = c(2, 4, 3, 2, 2, 2, 3))
```

What I currently have is this.

```
ggplot(data = df, aes(x = name, y = id)) +
  geom_dotplot(stackdir = "center", binaxis = 'y', dotsize = 0.5, binwidth = 1) +
  scale_y_continuous(breaks = seq(0, 3, 1), minor_breaks = seq(0, 3, 1))
```

[image]

However, this does not seem to show me all the dots per `id` (it only shows me 1 dot for each `id`, even though `id` 0 for `name1` has a count of 2).

How would I go about fixing this?

Comment: What is your expected output? Are you expecting to see 2 dots for (name1, id1) and 4 dots for (name1, id2)? or are you expecting to see (name1, id2) dot twice the area of (name1, id1) dot? Do you have to use `geom_dotplot`?

Comment: @Peter I would like to see 1 dot for each count. So for name = `name1` and id = `0` I would like to see 2 dots (which is how I expect a dotplot to work. And yes, I need it to be in geom_dotplot()

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't know of a way to pass summarised data to `geom_dotplot()`.  Instead, you can `uncount()` it first:

```
library(ggplot2)
library(tidyr)

df <- data.frame(name = c("name1", "name1", "name1", "name1", "name2", "name2", "name2"),
                 id = c(0, 1, 2, 3, 0, 1, 2),
                 count = c(2, 4, 3, 2, 2, 2, 3)) %>%
  uncount(count)

ggplot(data = df, aes(x = name, y = id)) +
  geom_dotplot(stackdir = "center", binaxis = 'y', dotsize = 0.5, binwidth = 1) +
  scale_y_continuous(breaks = seq(0, 3, 1), minor_breaks = NULL)
```

[image]

Comment: The uncount really did the trick. I guess I was wrong to assume I could give a count to create the dots. Thanks!